# Correct way to integrate client side libraries (adminLTE) in vue js 2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, adminlte

I'm trying to integrate [adminLTE](https://adminlte.io/) with vue.

I created a a new app with `vue create admin-cli`

Then I did `npm install admin-lte --save` as stated here: https://adminlte.io/docs/2.4/installation

Now npm downloads everything to node_modules/admin-lte

I don't really know how to integrate adminLTE with the vue app. I guess I could just copy every file I need to the assets folder but I'd like to use some tool to spare me the job.

From a vue component (App.vue for example) I can do like this

```
<img alt="Avatar" src="~admin-lte/dist/img/avatar.png">
```

The "~" will point to node_modules (https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#transform-rules)

But I cant use it in public/index.html to include all the css and js dependencies of adminLTE.

I think I have to configure webpack to copy all the needed dependencies, but I don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: Hey did you ever figure out the best way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

just use [this](https://devjin0617.github.io/vue2-admin-lte/)
It is an Admin LTE based on Vue.

[image]